# Circular linked list code is getting into infinite loop

Tags: python, oop, linked-list, iterator, circular-list

I have defined by Circular Linked List like this.

```
class Link(object):
    def __init__ (self, data, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class CircularList(object):

    def __init__ ( self ):
        self.first = Link(None, None)
        self.first.next = self.first

    def insert_first ( self, item ):
        new_link = Link(item)
        new_link.next = self.first
        self.first = new_link

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.first
        first = current
        while current.next != first:
            yield current
            current = current.next

    def __str__(self):
        return str([Link.data for Link in self])

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

And I insert item to my list

```
a = CircularList()
a.insert_first(4)
a.insert_first(5)
```

I want to have a string representation of my circular list, but it looks like `__iter__()` is looping infinitely. I can I correctly define my iterator, and get a correct string representation?

Comment: Does it work if you replace `first = current` with `first = self.first` in `__iter__`?

Comment: @ndmeiri No, it does not work

Comment: Your `insert_first` method is incorrect -- you do not update the pointers properly. I'd recommend taking a few sample cases, tracing them on paper and verifying that it indeed does not work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry but Im really new to object-oriented programming and can't understand what you are saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break the steps down.

First, I rename `Link` to `Node`.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Links aren't the same as nodes - nodes are what hold your data, and links connect two nodes together.

Next, the `CircularList` class, needs some changes.

`__init__` will need to initialise an *empty* list. That means no nodes *at all*. For the sake of convenience, I define `self.last` to *greatly* simplify the code (note, *greatly*, you will have a harder time of things otherwise).

```
class CircularList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = self.last = None
```

For `insert_first`, you will need to take care of a corner case when the list is empty, and the general case. Update `self.first` and `self.last` accordingly.

```
def insert_first(self, item):
    if self.first is None:
        self.first = self.last = Node(item)
        self.first.next = self.first
    else:
        self.first = Node(item, self.first)
        self.last.next = self.first
```

Your `__iter__` method should also respond in kind. Comments inlined.

```
def __iter__(self):
    # corner case - yield empty list
    if not self.first:
        yield []
    else:
        # start by yielding the head node
        yield self.first
        cur = self.first.next
        # iterate as long as you do not see the head node again 
        while cur is not self.first:
            yield cur
            cur = cur.next
```

The other methods remain the same. Test code:

```
a = CircularList()
for i in [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:
    a.insert_first(i)

print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

**Full Code Listing**

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class CircularList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = self.last = None

    def insert_first(self, item):
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = self.last = Node(item)
            self.first.next = self.first    
        else:
            self.first = Node(item, self.first)
            self.last.next = self.first

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.first:
            yield []
        else:
            yield self.first
            cur = self.first.next
            while cur is not self.first:
                yield cur
                cur = cur.next

    def __str__(self):
        return str([Link.data for Link in self])

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Comment: you are the best

Comment: @EricKim I hope this answer has taught you something. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, your code works PERFECTLY, but for insert_first(), if I put self.first = Link(item), self.last = Link(item), for some reason it doesn't work. (it seems to iterate infinitely). You did self.first = self.last = Link(item) on one line, but I tried doing it in two lines, then it doesn't work. do you know why?

Comment: @EricKim The trick there is that self.first and self.last need to point to the exact same object, otherwise the code fails on the `cur is not self.first`, because `is` checks the identity of the object (AKA, the `id`, and they won't be the same with your change).

Comment: ohhhh that makes sense. Thank you!!